# I want to send email for more than one user to Mailtrap

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-blade

I tried to send an email to a user and arrived at Miltrap
Now I put all the users on my system (table users in database) and introduced them to checkboxs and I want to send one email to more than one user or to all users and I did not see the result on the mailtrap
This is the code

MailboxController.php

```
public function form(Request $request)
{

    $users = User::where('id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)->get();
    return view('MailBox.form',compact('users'));
}
public function contact(Request $request)
{
    //$emails = [];
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'subject' => 'min:3',
        'message' => 'min:10']);
    $data = array(
        'email' => $request->email,
        'subject' => $request->subject,
        'bodyMessage' => $request->message
        );
    Mail::send('MailBox.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->from('info@dev-any.com');
        $message->to($data['email']);
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });
    Session::flash('success', 'Your Email was Sent!');
    return redirect('/dashboard/mailbox');
}
```

Web.php

```
Route::get('/mailbox', 'MailboxController@form')->name('mailbox.form');
Route::post('/mailbox/contact', 'MailboxController@contact')->name('contact');
```

form.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('contact') }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
<div class='form-group col-md-6'><strong>Select User :</strong><br>
            <input type="checkbox" id = "chckHead" name="chk_all" value="" onchange="checkall()" id='allcb' /><strong> Check All </strong>  </br>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class = "chcktbl" onchange="check()" name="email" id="email" value={{ $user->id }}></td>
            <td>{{ $user->name }}</td></br>
            </tr>

            @endforeach
            </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label name="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label name="message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control">Type your message here...</textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-success col-md-6">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.chcktbl').click(function () {
    var length = $('.chcktbl:checked').length;      
    if (length > 3) {
        // alert(length);
        $('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').attr('enable', true);
    }
    else {
        $('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').attr('enable', false);
    }
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#chckHead').click(function () {
    if (this.checked == false) {
        $('.chcktbl:checked').attr('checked', false);
    }
    else {
        $('.chcktbl:not(:checked)').attr('checked', true);
    }
});
$('#chckHead').click(function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the email checkbox, and modify the validation

```php
<input type="checkbox" class="chcktbl" onchange="check()" name="email[]" id="email" value={{ $user->id }}>
```

Comment: Also not sent
what about script ? Is it true?

Comment: with ```name="email[]"``` you send email data as an array, so ```$message->to($data['email']);``` contains array too. Would you please post the response of your application?

Comment: this error show : Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. #10060]

Comment: It's mailtrap problem
Please take a look for documentation here https://mailtrap.io/

Comment: Thank you very much